# how to hit total 1000 ssh commands using jmeter by 1000 users (1command/user) using 1 ssh connection

Tags: jmeter

how to hit total 1000 ssh commands using jmeter by 1000 users (1command/user) using 1 ssh connection.

Also is there a way to do ssh connection using private connection in Jmeter ?

Any leads will be helpful.

Thanks Balaram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test doesn't make a lot of sense a it is not realistic scenario, i.e. you cannot have 2 users sharing one SSH connection as it is not possible at the [SSH protocol level](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#page-4)

Using JMeter you can open 1 session per user, you can use the same username and password (or [public key](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Generating-Your-SSH-Public-Key)), however each JMeter thread (virtual user) will create a separate SSH session (connection) to the server.

So you can implement the above scenario in JMeter, the easiest way is going for [SSH Command](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler#ssh-command) sampler which can be parameterised via i.e. [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)

[image: JMeter SSH Sampler]

You can get SSH Sampler as a part of **SSH Protocol Support** bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter SSH Protocol Support Plugins Manager]